# Cypher query with infinite relationship takes forever

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to implement a simple graph db for NYC subway.

There are a total of 493 stops with a label :STOP and a property {name:" stop name "}, eg:

```
(n:STOP {name:"Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St"}) -[:DIRECT {dist:0.5}]-> (m:STOP {name:"238 St"})
```

with a total of 566 relationships [:DIRECT {dist: ...} ]

What I'm trying to get is a list of nodes and sum(dist) between them starting from a particular stop and return only the ones with a certain sum(dist) away, the cypher query runs perfectly when I limit the number of relationships, eg:

```
match p=(n:STOP {name:"Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St"})-[:DIRECT*1..10]-(m:STOP) 
WITH n,m,     
     reduce(acc=0, x in relationships(p)| acc + x.dist) as x 
WHERE x < 5 
return n.name, m.name, x 
limit 10
```

The problem starts when I specify -[:DIRECT*]-
The query pretty much fails after about 10 min with unknown error

Here is the profiling for the query with a limit:

```
==> +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | n.name                        | m.name                    | x                  |
==> +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "238 St"                  | 0.33               |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "231 St"                  | 0.78               |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "Marble Hill - 225 St"    | 1.1800000000000002 |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "215 St"                  | 1.6400000000000001 |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "207 St"                  | 2.02               |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "Dyckman St"              | 2.47               |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "191 St"                  | 2.89               |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "181 St"                  | 3.3400000000000003 |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "168 St - Washington Hts" | 4.04               |
==> | "Van Cortlandt Park - 242 St" | "157 St"                  | 4.5600000000000005 |
==> +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> 10 rows
==> 
==> ColumnFilter(0)
==>   |
==>   +Slice
==>     |
==>     +Extract(0)
==>       |
==>       +Filter(0)
==>         |
==>         +ColumnFilter(1)
==>           |
==>           +Extract(1)
==>             |
==>             +ExtractPath
==>               |
==>               +Filter(1)
==>                 |
==>                 +TraversalMatcher
==> 
==> +------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------+
==> |         Operator | Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                          Other |
==> +------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------+
==> |  ColumnFilter(0) |   10 |      0 |             | keep columns n.name, m.name, x |
==> |            Slice |   10 |      0 |             |                   {  AUTOINT3} |
==> |       Extract(0) |   10 |     40 |             |                 n.name, m.name |
==> |        Filter(0) |   10 |      0 |             |               x < {  AUTOINT2} |
==> |  ColumnFilter(1) |   10 |      0 |             |           keep columns n, m, x |
==> |       Extract(1) |   10 |    110 |             |                              x |
==> |      ExtractPath |   10 |      0 |           p |                                |
==> |        Filter(1) |   10 |     10 |             |            hasLabel(m:STOP(4)) |
==> | TraversalMatcher |   10 |     45 |             |              m,   UNNAMED52, m |
==> +------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to share your database? Do you have an index for :STOP(name) ?

Comment: The problem is, if you don't specify a limit and no direction it will generate a huge number of paths and can't stop eagerly when it found your 10 paths. Did you try the new query planner with the `cypher 2.1.experimental` prefix?

Comment: @MichaelHunger, CREATE INDEX ON :STOP(name) - was done before, so yes.
Totally agree with you and yes I have tried adding "cypher 2.1.experimental" - same outcome. 

I'm not sure what would be the best way to export the graph so I can share it.

Also, I've read quite a bit and it seems like I might be getting better results if I use Java Core - what do you think?

Comment: Just zip the graph.db directory and put it on dropbox. You very probably are faster with the core-api, I just wanted to see why this cypher query is soo slow on your dataset. Please send the db to michael at neo4j.org